# How Open *.jar File? Is It the Same as .*exe for Windows?

Tags: java, jar

I'm new to Java. I just created my first Java application using NetBeans. Here's the source code:

```
package helloWorld;


public class Main {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        System.out.println( "What's your name, sparky? =]" );
        String sparkysName = System.console().readLine();

        System.out.println( "Was that so hard, " + sparkysName + "? =P" );

    }

}
```

After compilation I have *helloWorld.jar* file. And here comes my dummy questions...

1. Is *.jar extension something like *.exe for Windows, just for Java (will work on any platform with Java on it)?
2. I can run my *helloWorld.jar*, but it stays on screen just for 0.1 second so I can't see anything... I think there was an error. How can I fix it (NetBeans won't complain and I could compile it)?

**Edit #1:**

In my *.jar file inside I have *Main.class* that owns main(). So it isn't the problem.
I just discovered that it tries to tell me something like:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a double click to execute it, but the user will only see any result if you use a UI framework like Swing or AWT.

In your case, System.out.printlns and System.console().readLine() will be only interactable by the command console.

Comment: What would you prefer for newbie like me? Swing or AWT?

Comment: Swing, the AWT GUI library is only used as the base for Swing nowadays

Answer (score 2):

1. jar is java archive. Unlike .exe it cannot be executed on the processor, but on the JVM. So the actual command to execute a jar file, is `java -jar jarfilename` meaning you call the java virtual machine with your jar file as a parameter.
2. This is because it doesn't wait to anything, it just print two lines and quit. If you run it from command line, you will see. If the execution of the program is longer / the program waits for some input, it will not be closed that fast

Comment: I would add in addition that not all JAR files can be executed in this fashion.  Only those which include the optional MANIFEST.MF file containing a Main-Class entry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just double-click on your .jar to open it if java is installed and in your PATH, or run `java -jar "jar_path"` in cmd.  Also, it's not stopping because execution is done after your last instruction so it exits.  I don't remember the exact syntax but try reading a key from the user.  It'll pause your program until you press a key.

Edit: I think `System.in.read();` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A .jar file uses the standard Zip compression format.  You can open any jar file with anything that can open Zip files.  (WinZip, WinRar, 7-zip, etc.).

Comment: I don't speak about *.jar used as archive. Read my question once again!

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to answer your question on .jars vs. .exes on Windows, but I think we were on different pages.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Jar file is a normal Zip file, so you can open it with any program capable of opening zip files - to look inside.

To run code from a Jar file you need to name the main class in the manifest file: a special file at a special location with a special format. JDK/JRE looks inside the Jar file for this file and runs the class specified there.

Google for MANIFEST.MF.

Answer (score 0):

A jar file just compresses all Java files together. You can select all the files of your application and put them in a jar file. But the jvm is capable of executing a jar file. For this, you need to specify which of the java files (residing in the jar) has the main method. This has to be done when creating the jar.

So, a jar file can be run on any platform which has JVM installed in it. In your case, you cannot see the commandline because you are just displaying something and when the program is terminated, the commandline vanishes. Hence, try doing this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int i = br.readLine();
```

at the end of the file and you can see the commandline not being terminated and waiting for your input. It works just the same way in a c or a c++ application where the commandline vanishes unless you have a getch() or something similar to it.

For your reference, you have tutorial on how to create and run Jar files [here.](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/)